# How to generate OpenAPI YAML specification at build stage?

Tags: java, gradle, swagger, openapi, springfox

I am using springfox-swagger2 to expose API specification.
`compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2'`

```
springfox:
  documentation:
    swagger:
      v2:
        path: /v1/api-docs
```

I have configured Swagger2Configuration and use Swagger annotations in controllers.

I need to generate a static OpenAPI YAML or JSON file as a result of a separate Gradle task or as build result.

How to do it?